# What is the issue with this query?

Tags: php, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO [dbp_mod].[dbo].[Logs] (UserID, DB_Type, DB_Name, TableName, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, SearchFields, SearchValues, Action, ActionIP, ActionTime) VALUES (1, 'DBF', 'E:\dbf\dbtest.dbf', 'E:\dbf\dbtest.dbf', 'f3', '8', '10', 'f1', '1', 'Edited', '192.168.2.124', GetDate());
```

What is the issue with this query? It is Running correctly in the Management Studio, but yields

`Warning: mssql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource in` error with PHP

```
$query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Logs] (UserID, DB_Type, DB_Name, TableName, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, SearchFields, SearchValues, Action, ActionIP, ActionTime) 
        VALUES ($data[UserID], '$data[DB_Type]', '$data[DB_Name]', '$data[TableName]', '$data[FieldName]', '$data[OldValue]', '$data[NewValue]', '$data[SearchFields]', '$data[SearchValues]', '$data[Action]', '$data[ActionIP]', GetDate()); ";

    echo "<br>$query";
    if(!mssql_query($query, $db)){
        $successFlag = FALSE;
    } else {
        $successFlag = TRUE;
    }
```

I'm sure that I'm selecting db with `$db` as

```
INSERT INTO [dbp_mod].[dbo].[Logs] (UserID, DB_Type, DB_Name, TableName, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, SearchFields, SearchValues, Action, ActionIP, ActionTime) VALUES (1, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Logged in ', '192.168.2.124', GetDate());
```

did work in both PHP and Management Studio

Comment: WARNING: your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: There IS a problem with your connection to the db.  That would be the `$db` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error is with your DB connection, not your SQL. Inspect the db handle to see what the problem is.

What methods are available to verify a db handle is "good"?